# how can I profile class methods of my python app?

Tags: python, profiler

In the past I've written python code with all functions in the same file, and I could profile my programs using the following code:

This is a decorator I wrote:

```
def do_profile(cond):
    def resdec(f):
        if not cond:
            return f
        return profile(f)
    return resdec
```

And this is how I use it:

```
@do_profile(DO_PROFILE)
def my_func():
    return 1
```

I would then invoke `kernprof.py` on my script:

```
kernprof.py  -l my_program.py
```

In the meantime I got more familiar with OOP and I rewrote my program into many classes and the program is now started like this:

```
 if __name__ == "__main__":
     my_app = myApp()
     my_app.run()
```

`myApp` is a class which is also communicating heavily with other classes:

```
class myApp():
    @do_profile(DO_PROFILE)
    def foo_method(self, arg1):
        pass
```

I've added the `do_profile` decorator in front of each `myApp` method, but if I run `kernprof.py`, the resulting `.prof` file is empty

So what's the easiest way of profiling a methods of a class? I would really love to switch this on / off with a decorator and a flag.

**EDIT1:** I'm really interested in the easiest possible solution here. A find a decorator to be an elegant solution, but maybe things can be done easier. What I DO NOT want to do, is using stuff like `cProfile's` profile `profile.runctx('self.baz()', globals(), locals())` . That is not a practical solution when handling many classes and methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `profile` function is a decorator itself, and like most decorators, they need to be applied to functions only.

Luckily, class methods are basically functions that are bound to an instance when an instance is created. Thus, you can apply your decorator to any class method by putting it in the class definition by the methods themselves:

```
class myApp(object):
    @do_profile(DO_PROFILE)
    def foo_method(self, arg1):
        pass

    @do_profile(DO_PROFILE)
    def bar_method(self, arg2):
        pass
```

If you use python 2.6 or up, you can also create a [class decorator](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3129/) and apply the `profile` decorator to *all* methods on any given class. You'd apply it by placing the decorator right before the class definition:

```
@do_profile_all_methods(DO_PROFILE)
class myApp(object):
    def foo_method(self):
        pass
```

Such a decorator could look something like this:

```
import types

def do_profile_all_methods(cond):
    if not cond:
        return lambda c: c # Do nothing with the class; the 'null' decorator
    def profile_all_methods(klass):
        for name, attr in klass.__dict__.items():
            if isinstance(attr, types.UnboundMethodType):
                klass[name] = profile(attr)
        return klass
    return profile_all_methods
```

This decorator only applies the `profile` wrapper to direct methods, not any inherited from the base class.

Comment: How do you use this?  Can you give the complete working example?

Comment: @johnktejik: I'm applying the techniques to the setup that the OP has given in their question.  It's just a boolean defining wether or not profiling is applied, `DO_PROFILE = False` would easily set you up.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [Yappi](http://code.google.com/p/yappi/)

To profile a piece of code simply use:

```
import yappi
[...]
yapp.start()
some_function_that_needs_profiling()
yappi.print_stats()
```

Comment: so if `some_function_that_needs_profiling()` instantiates a bunch of objects, will their respective methods be profiled automatically?

Comment: on python3.5 I get an error
AttributeError: module 'yappi' has no attribute 'print_stats'

Comment: from their docs yappi:  Supports Python 2.6.x <= x <= Python 3.4